# Why can't a setter have the same name as the field?

Tags: dart

```dart
class Foo {
  int count = 0;

  set count(int i) => count = i; // Error

  set something(int i) => count = i; // Works
}
```

Why a setter `count` isn't allowed to have the same name as the field itself?

Comment: Because a variable is the same as having a field with both a setter and getter. So you already have a setter in this case which you are trying to override inside the same class. A `final` variable is the same as only having a `getter`. So you can actually have a `set` if you change your `count` to `final int count = 0;`.

Comment: Hi, I already know about the other things you mentioned, but your last line indeed is something I didn't know :) Can you please write it as answer. Although I didn't understand how can a final field be modified, is that an error?

Comment: `final` in Dart does just mean the variable does not have a `set`. In this case, we cannot really change the value of our `final count` even with our own setter since this setter would just call itself if you try set a value of `count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable in Dart is really just a field with a `set` and `get` method automatically assigned (only `get` when talking about `final` variables).

So in your case you are trying to override the `set` of `count` which does already have a `set` method. This is not possible in Dart and would also be confusing since we don't know which `set` we should then call if doing `count = 5`.

Since a `final` variable does only have a `get` we are actually able to do this:

```
class Foo {
  final int count = 0;

  set count(int i) => count = i;
}
```

However, this is kinda pointless in this example since if we are trying to use it:

```
void main() {
  Foo().count = 5; // Unhandled exception: Stack Overflow
}
```

We get a Stack Overflow exception since our `set count` uses its own `set` method since `count` does not have any `set` itself (since it is marked `final`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the setter (`set count`) for simplicity I used `count = i`, which makes the setter pointless. However, if we have some conditions there before we can set `count` field, I think setter does make sense. So, what's wrong in having the regular field `count` works as a getter and `set count` as setter?

Comment: Again, you will end up with two `set` methods which Dart cannot determine which one you want to call when trying to set a value for `count`. If you need to have some rules before calling `set` you need to create a private variable and manually have a `get` and `set` for that.

Comment: I understand the two `set` and there's no reason to not give priority to the declared setter. Not sure why they don't allow it, +1 for your efforts.

Comment: It is not a question about priority. It is about what should Dart do with: `set count(int i) => count = i;`? How do you point to the actually `set` for `count` so you prevent the stackoverflow? Or do you want to have some complicated rule that if you are inside the `set` method and call itself it should look for other `set` methods with lower priority?

Comment: Additional comment: *My Dart questions are mostly answered by you, @lrn and previously by @jamesdlin* It seems like only a few people are this good with the concept. Kudos!!!

Answer (score 0):

While Dart does not allow naming the setter the same as the variable, (as discussed in [julemand101's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67002809/258418) it is worth while noting that getter and setter can have the same name. I explicitly mention this since I came across unfortunate [examples where setter and getter were named differently](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getter-and-setter-methods-in-dart/). If I have a getter and setter I tend to make the variable private (add a leading underscore `_`). With this the restriction that the setter can't be named the same as the variable becomes somewhat moot, as long as the getter is non trivial, since otherwise dart will spit out a warning about "[unnecessary getters and setters](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_getters_setters.html)". This warning could be surpressed but I don't think it is worth while.

```
class Test {
  int _value = 0;

  set value(int value) {
    _value = value;
  }

  int get value { // ignore: unnecessary_getters_setters
    return _value;
  }
}
```

Given that the options I currently see as a dart beginner are:

- have a setter named differently than the getter (ugh, which user of my class is going to remember?)
- having to suppress a linter warning in the implementation (not great)

my personal choice is clearly the linter warning surpression in the implementation. Ugly at the implementation side but clean in use.